# Issues with Derivative Calculator Autograd

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, autograd

I am using Autograd, a wrapper for numpy that differentiates functions. The output is $f^\prime$. An example would be `tanh_prime = grad(np.tanh)` would return the first derivative of tanh.

Whenever I apply the output of a `grad` call to an array, I get an exception. For example, when a call `grad(np.tanh)(np.arange(5))`, I get

```
TypeError: Output [ 0.          0.76159416  0.96402758  0.99505475  0.9993293    
] can't be cast to float. Function grad requires a scalar-valued function. Try 
jacobian or elementwise_grad.
```

That array in the exception string is the gradient, but I can't store it because it's part of the exception. Furthermore, why is the exception being called since `np.tanh` is a scalar-valued function?

Comment: `np.tanh` is an elementwise function. Try `elementwise_grad`, maybe?

Comment: How is `tanh` an element-wise? Not saying you're wrong, but why?

Comment: Because it acts *elementwise* on `numpy` arrays. It is a built-in `ufunc`, that is the definition of a ufuncs functions in `numpy`. It even *says so in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tanh.html)*
 What do you think elementwise means? Don't conflate the mathematical notion of a "scalar-valued" function with what it means with regards to Python functions. Elementwise just means if I pass it an array, it returns an array with the function applied *elementwise* to the elements of the array.

Comment: I have sometimes seen this issue when a scalar-valued function returns a complex number for particular inputs. It might be worth checking if the return value has an imaginary component.